# Half fruit math problem

Tags: linear-algebra

My 4th grader daughter got this question:

There are 4789 peaches and mangoes.
Peaches are 1670 more than mangoes.

How many peaches and mangoes are there?

Her answer (which i agree) :

> Peaches = Y
>   Mangoes = X
>
> > X+Y = 4789
> >     Y=X+1670
> >
> > > (X+1670)+X=4789
> > >       2X+1670=4789
> > >       2X=4789-1670
> > >       X=3119/2
> > >       X=1559,5
> >
> > Y=1559,5+1670
> >     Y=3229,5
>
> 4789= 3229,5(Y) + 1559,5(X)

There are no half fruits, so possible solution:

> > add 0,5 to Peaches
> >
> > > 3230+1559 = 4789
> > >       But 1559+1670 = 3229 not 3230 (wrong answer)
> >
> > add 0,5 to mangoes
> >
> > > 3229 + 1560 = 4789
> > >       But 1560+1670 = 3230 not 3229 (still wrong)

This answer troubles me, as we are talking about fruits, there are no half fruits. Is easy to say that the mangoes are 1560 (adding half), but mathematically this is not correct.

Do you have any other solution?
Or can she post this answer?

Comment: The numbers given in the question are wrong.  $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ should share the same parity since they differ by $2Y$, which is an even integer.

Comment: I would post the answer with the halves.  It is the correct mathematical solution and I have seen half fruits.  Better half fruits than half truths.

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ is the number of mangoes then $x+(x+1670)=2x+1670=4789$. From this equation it is clear $x$ can't be an integer. So you either have to accept that there can be half fruits or there is a mistake in the exercise itself.